# How do I release all lucene .net file handles?

Tags: lucene, io, lucene.net

I want to run a process that completely destroys and then rebuilds my lucene .net search index from scratch.

I'm stuck on the destroying part

I've called:

IndexWriter.Commit();
IndexWriter.Close();
Analyzer.Close();
foreach (var name in Directory.ListAll()) { Directory.ClearLock(name); Directory.DeleteFile(name); }
Directory.Close();

but the process is failing because the is still a file handler on a file '_0.cfs'

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there an index reader holding a lock on that file... have you determined which process has the lock?

Answer (score 0):

Are you hosted in IIS? Try an `iisreset` (sometimes IIS is holding onto the files themselves).

Comment: (Sorry to resurrect an old comment). Under what conditions does iisreset hold the files? An iisreset is not appropriate for a multitenancy web server.  As Lucene is used by many large web projects, I'm sure they wouldn't all be expected to do this every time the index needs to be recreated.

Answer (score 0):

Just call `IndexWriter.DeleteAll()` followed by a `IndexWriter.Commit()`, it will remove the index content and will enable you to start off with an empty index, while already open readers will still be able to read data until closed. The old files will automatically be removed once they are no longer used.